# FusionPBX Failed(405) on Cisco 303 IP phone

Tags: cisco, voip, sip, freeswitch

Since yesterday, my phone started throwing a Failed(405) error when trying to register to a FusionPBX server. I have tried resetting to factory settings and reinstalling the FusionPBX server on multiple OS's several times, but unfortunately, without any luck. It did work before, but after a few hours it randomly started throwing this error on every FusionPBX installation I've made.

I have tried the solution provided in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/704245) already, but unfortunately without any luck. I'm running FusionPBX 3.8.4 on Debian 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port to 5063 or something other than what is currently being used. FreeSWITCH allows 5060-5069 with TCP or UDP by default.